# Microsoft Teams App + Keycloak Integration

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, keycloak, microsoft-teams

I'm building a Teams application, and I would like to use the teams logged user to authenticate in an external Identity Provider (keycloak), using the Microsoft credentials... Is it possible?

Currently, the app opens a popup with the keycloak username/password form, and the social login buttons (one of them is Microsoft). But keycloak doesn't seem to use the teams logged user, and I must insert the Microsoft credentials manually..

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. You could look into [Silent Authentication in Teams Tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-silent-aad) and how it is configured.

Comment: @Subhasish-MSFT - I can use the Silent Authentication with Keycloak? 

Currently, I'm using `window.location.href="https://[keycloak url]/auth/realms/EV/protocol/openid-connect/auth `, then in the redirect_uri I use Silent Authentication to get a GraphAPI token (same as in the example).

Comment: Are you passing the usreEmailId as loginHint to the microsoft login endpoint? Also can you share any screenshot or the manifest file.

Comment: @SébastienLeroux were you able to integrate Keycloak with teams?

Comment: @Subhasish  is there a working sample for keycloak integration?

Answer (score -1):

first, you need to get a token then redirect to oidc URL I am able to solve it by using OIDC sso configuration in keyclok that is working fine